# How to get tweets from the last year until now using Twitter API in java?

Tags: java, api, twitter

I have coded to find particular tweets from certain location using search tweet. But i want to find out tweet which was posted from the last year until now. I just get the result from the latest tweets today. How can i modify my code? this is my code using java and **twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar**

```
import twitter4j.GeoLocation;
import twitter4j.Query;
import twitter4j.QueryResult;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;

public class TweetFromParticularLocation {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        Twitter twitter= new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
//      
//      twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET_KEY);
//      twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET));

        String CONSUMER_KEY = "key";
          String CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET = "key";

        Twitter twitter= new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET);

        String accessToken = "key";
        String accessTokenSecret = "key";
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(accessToken,accessTokenSecret));

        try {
            Query query = new Query("#jumatberkah"); //kalau tweet nya kososng, maka outputnya terminated

            //-6.914744, 107.609810 -- latitude, longitude bandung
            //-6.2115, 106.8452 -- latitude, longitude jakarta
          //-.7893, 113.9213  -- latitude, longitude indonesia

            GeoLocation location = new GeoLocation(-6.2115, 106.8452); //latitude, longitude
            String unit = Query.MILES; // or Query.MILES;  Query.KILOMETERS;
            query.setGeoCode(location, 1, unit); //location, radius, unit

            QueryResult result; 

            do {
                result = twitter.search(query);
                List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();

                for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                    System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText()+"\n");
                }

            } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);

        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter [public Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) only provides a sampling of Tweets for up to a week back in time (7 days). If you need to search further back, you'll need to use the commercial [Gnip Historical APIs](https://gnip.com/historical/) from Twitter instead.

Comment: oh ya? I already know that... so, how can i use Gnip Historical APIs? Do you have a sample?

Comment: can you give me sample code for using Gnip Historical APIs or the tutorial link @andypiper ?

Comment: There are a range of samples on the Gnip support pages. http://support.gnip.com/code/search_api.html

Comment: how can i consume this api to my java code? Is is same to Twitter4j?  Should i make a accsess token to use this gnip @andypiper?

Comment: Gnip is a paid product so you'd need to get in touch with them for pricing and access details. It is not the same as Twitter4j, but it looks like Gnip4j might be an alternative. https://github.com/zauberlabs/gnip4j